# Can gdb fix an ARM alignment trap and continue to the next trap?

Tags: gdb, arm, alignment, assembly-trap

We are tracking down some alignment traps on our ARM project - gdb is very helpful at catching the first trap - is there a way to continue past an alignment trap (letting the kernel fix it) so we could collect info on more of traps? Right now we are fixing them one at a time, which is a bit tedious (we are getting better at recognizing what's causing the trap)

Comment: You should actually be able to write an exception handler for unaligned access that correctly loads what you want and continues.  It's not necessarily trivial and there is a performance hit, but it might be helpful.